# Best practice of checking if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I was having some issues in my conditions concerning undefined variables. What is, to sum it up, the best way to check if a variable is undefined?

I was mainly struggling with

```
x === undefined
```

and

```
typeof x === 'undefined'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use both ways to check if the value is `undefined`. However, there are little nuances you need to be aware of.

The first approach uses strict comparison `===` operator to compare against `undefined` [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

```
var x;
// ...

x === undefined; // true
```

This will work as expected **only** if the variable is declared but not defined, i.e. has `undefined` value, meaning that you have `var x` somewhere in your code, but the it has never been assigned a value. So it's `undefined` by definition.

But if variable *is not* declared with `var` keyword above code will throw reference error:

```
x === undefined // ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

In situations like these, `typeof` comparison is more reliable:

```
typeof x == 'undefined' // true
```

which will work properly in both cases: if variable has never been assigned a value, and if its value is actually `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess both, depending on what you're testing? If it's a property, I'd always use `x === undefined`, since it's clearer (and it seems faster).

As others said, `x === undefined` won't work if x is not declared. Personally, I find that an even better reason to use it, since normally I shouldn't be checking if a variable is declared at all — it would usually be a sign of a coding mistake.

I've seen a lot of the other version for testing arguments — `f = function(x) {if (typeof x == 'undefined') …}` — if I'm code-reviewing code like this I'll tell them to change it. We know for a fact the variable is declared, and making an habit of writing it that way increases the chance you'll waste time chasing typo bugs.

The main exception is when you're trying to check if a component or library was loaded or initialized correctly. `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') …` makes sense. But in the medium term, all this should become modules anyway, in which case the typeof test should in my opinion be phased out as harmful.

*(Also, personally, I prefer `if (window.jQuery === undefined)` for that case too. It's not portable for isomorphic code, though.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
x === undefined
```

does not work if variable is not declared. This returns `true` only if variable is declared but not defined.

Better to use

`typeof x === 'undefined'`

Comment: @dfsq Actually I did, it did not work on chrome console.
Am I missing something?

Comment: There is a little moment. Check my answer. It didn't work in your case because variable `x` is not defined. If it has been defined like `var x`, you can check if it's `undefined` with `=== undefined`.

Comment: @dfsq: This is new for me. Edited my answer to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of them.
If you would like to check if a variable is undefined or null you could use:

```
x == null
```

This results in true if x is undefined or null.